# Why would Doze feature need motion detection?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery-life, doze-mode

I do not see any reason mentioned by Google for [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/power-mgmt.html#behavior-doze) to get activated only when the device is stationary.
Is there any specific advantage for doing this only when the device is stationary? What is the need to even waste resources checking for motion detector readings, when this can simply be achieved whenever the screen is off.

I am asking this because my phone is in my pocket for most of the time and because of that Doze mode will not get activated. I think there are many more people like me, so I don't understand why google chose these specific constraints for Doze mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is based off of the assumption that the device is not being used at that time, so it will enter Doze Mode.  How do you know that Doze is not being activated?  Clearly while in your pocket, if you are walking/running or moving around, the device will detect motion and not enter Doze Mode.  That's how they chose to have it operate.

Here's an explanation of it taken from [here](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/94jCkmG4jff?linkId=17112398).

> Doze mode is different in that the entire device is taking a nap, not just the least-recently used apps (such is the case with App Standby). Doze mode is activated when the device is not plugged in, when the screen is locked, and when no motion has been detected for some time. These assumptions imply that the user has put down the device and walked away. So, when they come back and pick their phone up off the counter, it should not have dropped to 30% battery. It should, essentially, be in the exact state it was in when they placed it on the counter. Right?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but they could have used location sensors for that, why would they need motion sensor which would get activated even if sit at the same place shaking my leg when my phone is in my pocket. Location sensor would work perfectly in that case.

Comment: They could have yes, but chose not to for whatever reason.  I would assume something like if your GPS/location isn't working and each time it is checked, it is using data/wifi/battery to do so and if it is changing due to being in a building where location would jump around, the phone may not go into Doze Mode either then.

Answer (score 2):

### Screen v. motion

Consider an application like email, which periodically polls your mail server for new email and perhaps alerts you to new mail by making a sound or light notification. When you are physically awake, you may want to be informed in a timely manner when you receive email even if the screen is off, which requires application network access. This happens only if your device is not in doze mode. If you are physically asleep, it does not matter if your device is in doze mode and has delayed those email notifications to a later maintenance window.

---

### Location v. motion

Once a device enters doze mode, how would it decide to exit?

It can't use location sensors when in doze mode; GPS is a high power draw and WiFi/cell location needs network access, which is also a relatively high power operation. In order to check for whether to exit doze mode using location, it would have to exit doze mode.

A device can use motion sensors in doze mode. This is a relatively low power draw and does not require any network access. The power savings in reducing other operations must exceed the draw required for the motion sensors, otherwise doze would not make sense.